# Snippets to Make add to cart button sticky in woocommerce single page

Tags: woocommerce, sticky-footer

What snippet can I use to make the add to cart button in single product page sticky on scroll. Also, the button when clicked should lead to the checkout page.

Demo:
https://www.jumia.com.ng/fashion-men-trendy-sneakers-summer-new-casual-shoes-black-and-white-36640916.html

The above link explains my questions.

Regards: Denison

Comment: Have you tried CSS?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will appreciate if you could provide me with the CSS options to use and where to place it. Regards: Denison